# Detect dramatic increase in proportion among multiple classes

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, proportion, anomaly-detection

I would like to use some tool to detect spike in one class's proportion.

Assume I received roughly the same percentage of red, blue and yellow candies throughout time. That means the absolute number can go up and down for each type of candy but **the percentage for each candy will stay roughly the same**. For example, it could be

1. 80 red (28%), 90 blue (32%), 110 yellow (39%)
2. 1 red (33%), 1 blue (33%), 1 yellow (33%)

And these are totally fine.

I want a tool to **statistically** detect when a particular percentage is larger than usual. For example, let's say one day i received 5 red (71%), 1 yellow and 1 blue. That will trigger the warning that the percentage for red is abnormal.

My gut instinct told me i should use Chi-square test to test one class vs. the rest of the classes. Is that correct?

Comment: It would be hard to answer this without knowing a little more about your problem but maybe you just need a control chart? https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1740-9713.2004.024.x

Comment: Control charts for proportions:  https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section3/pmc332.htm

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen - that nist handbook is golden.  @ Devin, I'm a different breed of nerd, so standard disclaimers apply.  I would look at confidence interval for a sample proportion when thinking about it, you need a sample size large enough to say the CI for the sample is less aligned with what would be expected when drawn from the same population.  Personally, I would use bootstrap simulation to get a bottom-up sense of what the values should be, or should not be, assuming you had sufficient population sizes.

Answer (score 1):

First transform your observations into proportions, as you have mentioned. Then you can apply some outlier detection method. Using [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) or Median Absolute Deviation on each class will probably work quite well for a few classes.

Note: for N classes, the proportions can be fully described by N-1 numbers. Since the proportions sum to 100%. So one column is a redundant column and can be dropped.

Comment: Transforming to proportions looses to much information, 1/10 and 10/100 are the same proportions, but the uncertainty is vey different!

Comment: Fair point! One could add the total as a separate feature and also detect anomalies in that. This would be an ML type approach, not so statistically strong.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is: "I want a tool to statistically detect when a particular percentage is larger than usual." That is what outlier/anomaly detection methods are made for.

Those methods have different techniques for achieving this. There are good libraries available, see e.g. [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) for python libs. Among the most popular methods, that also work for a large number of classes, are e.g. k-nearest neighbor methods or [isolation forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html). Note, however, that they rather detect any kind of isolation, which might also be an isolated very small value as for instance the value $0.1\%$ in $(0.1\%, 24.9\%, 25\%, 25\%, 25\%)$. Or it could be an isolated value in the middle. Those anomalies would not give you high values of z-score.

Most anomaly detection methods provide you with an outlier score which is a measure of its "outlier-ness". That makes those methods particularly flexible since you can yourself decide about where to set the threshold, i.e. above which value of the outlier score a value is to be considered an outlier.

Answer (score 1):

So here (below) is a customizable tool (in R) that you can explore your problem with, and it is how I would think about the problem using a bottom-up approach.  You can re-run it a few times with the same settings to get a feel for what run-to-run differences look like and what your uncertainty in the estimate of the means might look like.

This [link](http://web.mit.edu/fustflum/documents/papers/basseville.pdf) is to a paper on abrupt change detection and is how I like to think about detecting abrupt changes.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(matrixStats)

#parameters 
num_boots <- 3000
num_draws <- 10

#make original population 
pop <- sample(x = c("a", "b", "c"), #put your values here
              size=1000,            #total population
              prob=c(1,1,1)/3,      #sum to 1, frequencies of values
              replace = T)

#convert to factor (makes compute convenient)
pop <- as.factor(pop)

#get stats on it
summary(pop)

#prep for loop
log_store <- matrix(NA, num_boots, length(levels(pop))) %>% as.data.frame()

#bootstrapping
for(i in 1:num_boots){
  y <- sample(pop,num_draws)
  
  for(j in 1:length(levels(pop))){
  log_store[i,j] <- length(which(y==levels(pop)[j] ) ) 

  }
}

#make summaries in a useful form
df <- data.frame(labels = levels(pop),
                 sample_mean    = colMeans(log_store),
                 sample_std_dev = colSds(log_store %>% as.matrix()),
                 sample_max = colMaxs(log_store %>% as.matrix()),
                 sample_min = colMins(log_store %>% as.matrix()) )

#print it
print(tibble(df))
```

My output looks like this:

[image: table showing summary stats resulting from code above]

So what do I get from this?

- mean number per draw should have about the same proportions as in population
- one standard deviation is about 1.5 units so, if I use rules of thumb, about 67% of the time my values should be within 1.5 units of the mean, and about 99% of the my values should be within about 4.5 units of the mean.

To get the 80/90/110 you would change the code to

```
pop <- sample(x = c("red", "blue", "yellow"), #put your values here
              size=280,            #total population
              prob=c(80,90,110)/280,      #sum to 1, frequencies of values
              replace = T)
```

If you only draw 7 per day then adjust 'num_draws' to be 7 instead of ten.

The result from that would be this:
[image: second set of results]

From this we see that most of the time we get 2-3 of each.  We would find it rather unlikely to get more than about 6 red candies.